# Populate text field with checkbox

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql-server

I have a table with a column on prices and the next column is a check box to mark whether that item was paid. I was wondering how I could populate the text box with the amount when the check box is clicked.

Code:

```
<table> 
  <tr> 
    <td>Procedure</td> 
    <td>Amount</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <input type="text" size="20" value="" class="currency"> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you show some sample HTML for this?

Comment: <code><table> <tr> <td>Procedure</td> <td>Amount</td> <td align="center"><input type="checkbox"></td> <input type="text" size="20" value="" class="currency"> </tr> </table><code> The values are being pulled from a mysql database.

Comment: That HTML appears to be in invalid.  The last `input` isn't in a cell.

Comment: What have you tried, and what went wrong? This is not a "show me the codez" site, but a site for questions about programming languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Procedure</td>
        <td>Amount</td>
        <td align="center">
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" size="20" value="" class="currency">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript/jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $('table input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
        var input = $(this).closest('td').next('td').find('input');

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            var amount = $(this).closest('td').prev('td').text();

            input.val(amount);
        } else {
            input.val('');
        }
    });
});
```

See a working example at: http://jsfiddle.net/KTQgv/2/.

Comment: Perfect! Thats exactly what I was trying to do!

Answer (score 0):

Some code you can expand on:

```
<input type="checkbox" rel="textbox1" name="banana"/>
<textarea id="textbox1" ></textarea>
```

JS/jQuery:

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function(){
    var tb = "#"+$(this).attr('rel');
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
        $(tb).append(this.name + "\n"); 
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/hxkX3/

Answer (score 0):

Semantically, a checkbox isn't really the best control to choose to initiate an action. I would have an edit or pay (something actionable) button/icon which initiates the action of allowing the user to enter a value.

However for the purposes of your example, the `click` event of the checkbox is enough to be able to change the contents of your table cell from the displayed text (if any) to a textbox.

Given

```
<td id="row_1">Unpaid</td>
```

Using

```
$('#row_1').html('<input type="text" name="txtRow1" />');
```

is simplistic, but enough to enable the user to type in a value which could then be posted to the server during a `save` action.